# Yield a python reference multiple times in combination with zip

Tags: python, iterator, yield

I have a rather big array in numpy and want to yield the values to the next processing function in the pipeline. I have preallocated numpy arrays, as I don't want to allocate memory every time.

In one function I have to yield two values, the first one should be consumed directly afterwards, the second one a few pipeline stages later.

A simplified version of the code looks like the following:

```
import numpy as np

def numbers():
    ret = np.array([0])
    for i in range(4):
        ret[0] = i
        yield ret

def raw(gen):
    for d in gen:
        yield d

def add_ten(gen):
    for d in gen:
        yield d, d+10

def fun1():
    nums = numbers()
    g1, g2 = zip(*add_ten(nums))
    for n1, n2 in zip(g1, g2):
        print(n1, n2)

def fun2():
    nums = numbers()
    g = raw(nums)
    for n in g:
        print(n)

print("fun1")
fun1()

print("fun2")
fun2()
```

The code returns the following

```
fun1
[3] [10]
[3] [11]
[3] [12]
[3] [13]
fun2
[0]
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

The generator yields always the same reference, I just changed the underlying data. It's clear, if I would collect the data in a list, I'd see always the same value, as only the reference is stored.
However, I don't understand why `g1` from `fun1` does not work, while `g` from `fun2` works as expected.

Edit:
I'd  appreciate a workaround for this problem.

Edit:
In my application I pass these iterators into functions again and join them after a few steps.

Thierry already had a solution, if I would consume the values directly, thank you for that :)

```
def fun3():
    nums = numbers()
    g1, g2 = zip(*add_ten(nums))
    h1 = raw(g1)
    h2 = raw(g2)

    for n1, n2 in zip(h1, h2):
        print(n1, n2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the unpacking `*add_ten(nums)` that takes place in `g1, g2 = zip(*add_ten(nums))`.

The `add_tens` generator is immediately exhausted in order to create the unpacked list. This list, that will be the argument for `zip`, will contain:

```
(<your array>, <a new array containing 10>),
(<your array>, <a new array containing 11>),
(<your array>, <a new array containing 12>),
(<your array>, <a new array containing 13>),
```

as yielded by `add_ten`.

Once zipped, you will have:

```
(<your array>, <your array>, <your array>, <your array>),
(<a new array containing 10>, ... <a new array containing 13>)
```

When you print the content of `<your_array>`, you'll get `3` for each of the 4 references, as this is its current content.

In `fun2`, as you print the content of your array at each step of the iteration, you will get its successive contents, so 0, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Do know any workaround to avoid exhausting the first iterator?

Comment: `def fun1():    nums = numbers()    for n1, n2 in add_ten(nums):        print(n1, n2)` works as expected, but maybe your real use case is more complicated?

Comment: I wanted to pass these two new iterators to different functions, returning iterators again and join them again after a few steps